# Bittrex Exchange API call response now NULL but did work before

Tags: php

i have a problem with Bittrex API.

I did code a bot which was working last year fine, but today when i did test it again i see that the API from Bittrex is giving me now NULL as response.

Here is my code which i did use and like i say everythink was working fine, even in the website from bittrex api documentation they show this example:

```
    $nonce=time();

//--

$uri='https://api.bittrex.com/api/v1.1/account/getbalances?apikey='.$apikey.'&nonce='.$nonce;

//--

            $sign=hash_hmac('sha512',$uri,$apisecret);
            $ch = curl_init($uri);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('apisign:'.$sign));
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $uri);
            $execResult = curl_exec($ch);
            $Balances = json_decode($execResult, true);

var_dump($Balances);
```

Comment: not sure how we can help if a 3rd party API is broke.

Comment: I'll bet if you print out the value of `$execResult` you'll find something like an expired API key.

Comment: i see now that i did have a free space in the api key, so my api key was written wrong. thank you for the tip.